# Why is this .htaccess file routing static files to our front controller?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have been using the following `.htaccess` file for years. We are using `Apache 2.4.7`. And for some reason, static files seem to be hitting our front controller `index.php`!

For example: `https://example.com/apple-touch-icon.png` is being handled by our front controller as we can see the response header includes `X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3`.

Can anyone spot the issue?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Comment out `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php` and reload same `png` file.

Comment: That was the culprit! Perhaps you can add an answer so I can mark as the correct answer. Not exactly sure why the `IfModule !mod_rewrite.c` is ever executed?

Comment: Weird... `<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>` shouldn't be executed?! And if it was executed then your opposite block (`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`) can't also be executed?! But if the `ErrorDocument` was processed then it still shouldn't be a problem if the `.png` existed (which I assume it must do)? But you are behind a proxy... could that have anything to do with it? Incidentally, your rule to "Removes access to the system folder by users" will never do anything since the `RewriteCond` directive will always fail - the `REQUEST_URI` server variable always _starts with a slash_.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite I will need to look into that `RewriteCond` too! Being behind a proxy (AWS ELB) could be a culprit too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your `ErrorDocument` directive is causing this (loading `index.php` when some resource i.e. image, js or css file is not found.

You can comment out this directive to avoid this behavior:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: But this would presumably only be a problem if mod_rewrite was not enabled and the static resource does not exist?

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. At least in shown code `ErrorDocument` will fire only when `mod_rewrite` isn't loaded *somehow*.

Comment: This was the problem. Will still need to investigate why my conditional block fails. For now, this solves the initial question though, thanks!